# How does visual studio colorize c# code?

Tags: visual-studio, colorize

How does visual studio colorize c# code?

I know visual studio has an abstract class [LanguageService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb145427.aspx), it has a property [GetColorizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb133841.aspx), may colorize code.

But I can't find c# language's implement of [LanguageService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb145427.aspx) class.

Help me.

Or any other method to use visual studio's way to colorize is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking in the wrong place. The editor is the component that does the coloring, not the language service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885244.aspx

There is also sample code in the MSDN gallery that implements color highlighting for IronRuby.  I would study that code for an example.